# Read only buffered date from FILE object

Tags: c, file, posix, buffer

I'd like to read only what is already in the buffer of a `FILE` object, so that afterwards the buffer is empty (and I can use things like `sendfile` which operates on file descriptors). I came up with this function, which seem to work on my 64bit Linux installation:

```
int readbuf(FILE *stream, char buf[], size_t *size) {
    off_t pos = ftello(stream);
    if (pos < 0) return -1;
    off_t realpos = lseek(fileno(stream), 0, SEEK_CUR);
    if (realpos < 0) return -1;
    if (pos > realpos) {
        errno = EIO;
        return -1;
    }
    size_t bufsize = realpos - pos;
    if (bufsize > *size) {
        *size = bufsize;
        errno = ERANGE;
        return -1;
    }
    *size = bufsize;
    if (fread(buf, bufsize, 1, stream) < 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now I wonder, can I assume this to work on other POSIX compliant operating systems? (On systems that provide all the involved functions.)

Comment: This only works in cases where it's not even useful. See my answer for a different approach that's portable in the real world, even if not officially sanctioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the underlying file descriptor is seekable (either a regular file or a block device, unless you have other weird seekable objects on your system...) then there's no point in what you're trying to do. Just use `ftello` to get the logical position in the `FILE`, then discard the `FILE` and use `sendfile`. Using the already-buffered data in userspace is actually slower than `sendfile` anyway.

If the underlying file descriptor is not seekable, your whole approach does not work, because `lseek` will always return -1 and `ftello` will return `EOF`. A potential solution in this case:

- Use `dup` to make a new file descriptor referring to the same open file description.
- Open `/dev/null` write-only, and `dup2` it on top of the old file descriptor number used by the `FILE`.
- Reading from the `FILE` will succeed until the buffer is exhausted, then give read errors, since the file descriptor now refers to a non-readable file.
- At this point, you're free to read directly from the duplicated fd made in the first step. You're also free to `fclose` the `FILE`.

Comment: You're absolutely right! I use ftello and ignore the already buffered data. However, the speed improvement in my use case is in the error margin anyway. I just wanted to explore these APIs.

Answer (score 1):

For seekable files on Unix platforms you're supposed to be able to use fflush() to coordinate fd-based use with FILE*-based use, including for reading.  The full details are given in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01 and http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html.

This is an extension over what standard C gives you (unsurprisingly).

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe the stdio API guarantees that this would work on any system.  For instance, it might perform readahead if it notices the buffer is empty.

Your "solution" would be at most a specific implementation hack.

Comment: Are you sure it may perform a read ahead? Such a read might block which might cause all sorts of troubles in some applications.

Comment: In theory it could perform readahead, but it would have to (1) check whether fd is already nonblocking, (2) temporarily set it nonblocking, (3) attempt to fill the buffer, ignoring `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`, (4) restore the old blocking status. This is going to be 3 extra syscalls, which will make stdio 3 times slower, so you'd have to be stupid to attempt this "optimization" in an implementation. Perhaps, though, a specialized kernel interface for optimized stdio could make it efficient...